# Programmatic Reaction to Receiving New Email

Tags: automation, screen-scraping, email

I'm interested in automating some reactive work I do when receiving certain emails in one of my email accounts. What I would like to have happen is:

1. On receipt of new email in the account
2. If the new email passes the "Need to React" criteria (based on body content and subject line)
   3a.     Scrape some content out of the email body and subject lines
   3b.     Populate a template form (e.g. Excel spreadsheet) with the scraped data
   3c.     Print the populated form and save the populated form in some folder (e.g. as a pdf)

What's the best (defined as easiest to implement by myself) approach / combination of technologies for achieving this automation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have not done exactly what you are asking, but I know Microsoft Outlook has a Rules engine that can take incoming messages, check for various content, and then do various actions including running applications and/or scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Visual Studio Tools for Office if you are a c# person.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default

You can write an Outlook add-on that can do pretty much everything you have outlined above.